# Use update_all to update multiple objects with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, update-all

I have to update multiple objects with multiple values like this:

```
project.update(user_attributes: task_ids.collect { |id| { 'task_id': id } })
```

But the above code will result in `n + 1`. Any ideas in order to avoid `n + 1` here?

Comment: Is this code even valid? I mean - you are setting `task_id` for all users to `12213`, then `12323`, etc. to finally set it to `34563`. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Yes you are right. I was trying to write in a simpler way but here is the original code,

Comment: Why would here be `n + 1`? I dont see it

Comment: Calling: `project.update_all(user_attributes: VALUE)` should execute only one query:
`UPDATE 'projects' SET 'projects.user_attributes' = VALUE` (there might be additional `where` clause)

Comment: Here `VALUE` is dynamic.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that you are trying to set different values for different projects, right? Not the same value (for instance, array of IDs) for all of the projects?

Comment: its like updating all users of that project with the task ids and if any user dont exist then it should create the user.

Comment: @MartinZinovsky because if there are any users which are not present in the db then it will try to create those users.

Comment: @Ahmadhamza can you share the relation between `Project --> User --> Task` if I'm not mistaken its many to many between `Project and User`
`one to many between Project and Task` and `many to many between User and Task`

Comment: @Ahmadhamza Did you find a solution to your n+1 problem?

Comment: @Darkfish No i dint find any.